# Script working on all files in various subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

Trying to execute script on files located into multiple subdirectories (with different depth).
Im using script with arguments, Tried:

```
for i in "/home/working_dir_with_subdirs"/* ; do
     /opt/my_script -e -x "$i" "$i"/* "$i"/..
done
```

But only files in main directory `/home/working_dir_with_subdirs` was loaded by script. Files from subdirectories was not loaded, In terminal I saw that script is trying to execute subdirectory as a input file, not files inside directory.

Found some examples with `find` command, but files in subdirectories got different extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find /home/working_dir_with_subdirs/ -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 -n1 /opt/my_script -e -x
```

This would call `/opt/my_script` once for each file located in `/home/working_dir_with_subdirs` and its subdirectories.

If your script can accept multiple files as arguments, you  could drop the `-n1`:

```
find /home/working_dir_with_subdirs/ -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 /opt/my_script -e -x
```

This would call your script with multiple files as arguments, rather than once per file.

In both cases, the `-print0` on `find` and the `-0` on `xargs` are to correctly handle filenames that contain whitespace.